# What is the python equivalent to the "*" list all command?

Tags: python-3.x

What character do I use similar to "*" in other languages to list/see all of the files, where it doesn't matter what the beginning part is but they all end if say `.traj`.

So like I want to list the following files from a directory with the following file names

```
test1. exe
test1.traj
test2.exe
test2.traj
test3.exe
test3.traj
```

where I want to only list:

```
test1.traj
test2.traj
test3.traj
```

in other languages I might do:

```
print, *.traj
```

Comment: What "languages" do you do this with?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is `Python3` as that's what you have tagged.

Use the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html)

Like so:

```
files = glob.glob('*.traj')

for f in files:
    print(f)
```